# Git Clone Repo from virtualbox Ubuntu 14.04 server http protocol

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, tortoisegit, ubuntu-server

I made a git repo on my virtual machine in /var/www/test

Is there any simple way for me to clone this repo from my host machine via http protocol ?
Trying with gittortoise/gitbash passing my http protocol but it seems that it doesnt find any repo on it, thou there it is for 100%

Well I'm able to access it via web browser

Configuration(Not enough reputation to post images here :/ ):

http://pokazywarka.pl/ft7k05/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `git update-server-info` on the repo in the virtual machine. Afterwards activate the **post-update** hook:

On the virtual machine go to the `.git/hooks` directory. There should be some files with the ending `.sample`. Look for the `post-update.sample` file. To activate this hook just rename it to `post-update`.

If this file is not there, simply create it with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec git update-server-info
```

Make sure that the file is executable (`chmod 755 post-update`).

Comment: You are my hero bro <3